# How to save as PNG to tkinter's Image(Penguin)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMM2a.png)

when I click file>>save as `png`... 
It will save as `png` to that penguin. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but the image must be a tkinter PhotoImage.

The picture of your program suggests that it's not a photoimage. However; google "tkinter PhotoImage" and you will find information on how to build one pixel by pixel or however you want. Once you have a photoimage, saving it is easy:

```
image.write('some_name.png', format='png')
```